# Redirect Gatsby blog to React subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

so I have a React static main website hosted on Netlify. I also have a Gatsby blog hosted as a separate repo on Netlify.

How would I redirect the blog to be a subdirectory of the main website.

So when someone types main-site.com/blog it takes them to my-blog.netlify.app

I have been trying _redirects but it never redirects to the blog. It just redirects back to main-site.com.

Here’s one redirect I tried so far:

## In blog

/* https://main-site.com/blog/:splat

## Main site

/blog https://my-blog.netlify.app/:splat

Thanks for any info on this!

I have been trying _redirects but it never redirects to the blog. It just redirects back to main-site.com.

Here’s one redirect I tried so far:

## In blog

/* https://main-site.com/blog/:splat

## Main site

/blog https://my-blog.netlify.app/:splat

I’ve tried everything from similar posts but it hasn’t worked.